# .count or subset on one line?

Tags: python, count, subset

To replace these 10 lines of code (works):

```
CC=[]
for X in combinations(AA,3):
    DEL=0
    for Y in BB:
        if 0< list(chain(*X)).count(Y):
            pass
        else:
            DEL=1
    if DEL==0:
        CC.append(X)
```

...with these 2 lines of code (works perfectly):

```
BBB = set(BB)
CC=[X for X in combinations(AA,3) if BBB.issubset(chain(*X))]
```

...

...

But to remplace these 10 lines of code (works):

```
CC=[]
for X in combinations(AA,3):
    DEL=0
    for Y in BB:
        if 0 < list(chain(*X)).count(Y) < 3 :
            pass
        else:
            DEL=1
    if DEL==0:
        CC.append(X)
```

...how to do ?

is there a dedicated function ?

Comment: it looks like fortran... Could you please explain what your goal is? What are the inputs?

Comment: `collections.Counter` might be useful.  `collections.Counter(chain(*X))` gives you a dictionary where the keys are combinations and the values are counts.  It's easy then to filter that to find the values that occur exactly 1 or 2 times in chain(*X), and check if BBB is a subset of those.

Comment: Please explain *what the code is supposed to do*

Comment: Also, those two pieces of code look the same to me... what's the difference?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga first one checks whether Y exists at all in chain(*X), second one checks whether precisely 1 or 2 instances of Y exist in chain(*X).

Comment: Oh, the `< 3`, didn't see it

Answer (score 1):

yes,

```
max(Counter(chain(*X)).values())<3
```

Thanks slothrop

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).